# Running console-based executable inside another process through reflection results in "The handle is invalid" IOException

Tags: c#

I've uploaded my .exe file to my SQL server with Entity Framework, but when I try to execute my .exe file, I get the following exception:

> Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

And this is how I am trying to do it

```
private void LoadBin_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] bin = Database.GetByte(BinList.SelectedItem.ToString());
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(bin);
    MethodInfo method = assembly.EntryPoint;
    method.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

The exception is being thrown when I am trying to invoke it, my Main method does not have `string[] args`.

> Activated Event   Time    Duration    Thread  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.IOException: The
>   handle is invalid.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()    at
>   System.Console.set_Title(String value)    at
>   SimpleExternal.Program.Main()    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,
>   Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[]
>   parameters)    at Loader.MainWindow.LoadCheat_OnClick(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\Broder\Source\Repos\Loader\Loader\Loader\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
>   40    9.00s

When loading the file via `runPE` and hosting the process in another it works great, but when trying to run it with assembly is when I get the error.

Comment: What is the *full* exception, including its callstack and any inner exceptions? Have you tried debugging the code? You can get the full exception by calling Exception.ToString(). Most likely your main method is throwing.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried doing that just now.. System.IO.IOException: The Handle is invalid What I don't understand why it works great when running it with RunPE and hosting it in another process.

Comment: Without the *code* of your Main function it's impossible to answer. Although this method in the stack `System.Console.set_Title` is a strong indication - Console, what Console?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The code in my main function that i'm trying to run is just Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Console.set_Title may come from some runtime wrappers around your Main, or maybe from your code within that DLL/EXE. I really don't know, but that's not important. Important is that it runs when it is ran as standalone app. This means that some something was not prepared correctly when you ran it the other way.

I guess, just ensure that your current application that loads&runs this dll/exe also has a Console Window allocated. If you don't want it, then allocate it and hide it. Otherwise, any attempt to use Console class's features that touch Console Window will fail, because, well, there **will be no console**. The "handle" you see in that message refers to HWND, the handle-to-window.

Of course, you may also try to modify the code that dll/exe is built from to not use console window, or to check-if-there-is-a-console beforewards, or at the very least have a try/catch around all blocks of code that try to touch the console window.

For example, if Console.WriteLine is used for logging or status reporting, you may change that to System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine instead

Comment: The project runs fine standalone, and it works fine when I inject it with runPE into another process from the SQL server like this:             `RunPe.Run(Path.Combine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), "ilasm.exe"), "", bin, 4, ref num);` Could it be because my project I am launcing it from is a WPF, while the other project I am trying to start is a Console Project?

Comment: And yes, the whole point of my answer was to direct your attention at the fact that your new host exe is not a console application, and that's why the loaded exe/dll that assumes to have a console window - fails, because it does not find the console window.

Comment: Since indeed your new-host-application is not a console-based application, just simply add a console widow to it. Console is not magic either. WPF/Forms/etc frameworks simply don't open a console because they don't needed it. But that does not mean they can't have it. Search for "open console in WPF" or "allocate console window WPF" and you will surely find how to open a console window. Then, if you don't want it, you can HIDE that window but keep it open. This way, your executed-dll/exe should be happy to have a console window.

Comment: However, doing this may make reading/writing to is STDIO a bit harder. If running is not enough and if you want to do that too, then starting that dll/exe as a separate process would be easier for you. But then, you probably are aware of it, and since you are "RunPE"ing that, you want it to be hidden. Sorry, that's just tradeoffs everywhere.

Comment: I don't want it to be hidden, I only did that RunPE thing to see how it works, and if I could get it working. Starting it as a seperate process seems like a good thing to do, I'll need to try that. Thanks.